# Mongodb crashes after trying to sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, crash

I'm running mongodb 2.4.10 on a raspberry pi 3b. After few days it started to randomly crash and doesn't start without --journal. I created new database, but again it started to crash. After each crash it requires --repair.

What I noticed is it crashes after trying to sort

```
User.find({}).limit(10).sort({
    messages: -1
}).exec(function(err, docs) {
    ...
});
```

But it works fines with find

```
User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    ...
});
```

Here's full log of mongodb

```
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.356
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.356 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.356
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=754 port=27017 dbpath=db 32-bit host=raspberrypi
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten]
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB binary.
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults to off for 32 bit and is currently off.
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten]
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.10
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] build info: Linux bm-wb-03 3.19.0-trunk-armmp #1 SMP Debian 3.19.1-1~exp1+plugwash1 (2015-03-28) armv7l BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_55
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.386 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "db" }
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.441 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Sat Feb 11 05:56:02.442 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Sat Feb 11 05:56:03.724 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:43800 #1 (1 connection now open)
Sat Feb 11 05:56:39.087 [conn1] assertion 13097 Unsupported projection option: messages ns:test.users query:{ id: 378418036.0 }
Sat Feb 11 05:56:53.794 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:43800 (0 connections now open)
Sat Feb 11 05:57:01.512 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:43960 #2 (1 connection now open)
Sat Feb 11 05:57:01.786 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:43962 #3 (2 connections now open)
Sat Feb 11 05:57:01.787 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:43964 #4 (3 connections now open)
Sat Feb 11 05:57:01.787 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:43966 #5 (4 connections now open)
Sat Feb 11 05:57:08.329 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:43974 #6 (5 connections now open)
Sat Feb 11 05:57:09.474 Invalid access at address: 0x6b70f6c7 from thread: conn3

Sat Feb 11 05:57:09.474 Got signal: 7 (Bus error).

Sat Feb 11 05:57:09.479 Backtrace:
0x664160 0x16e370 0x16e6c0 0x766031a0 0x3bfa40 0x433a5c 0x430844 0x431428 0x3c5dc8 0x3c81a4 0x182474 0x64aa08
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x1c) [0x664160]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x2a0) [0x16e370]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo24abruptQuitWithAddrSignalEiP9siginfo_tPv+0x1fc) [0x16e6c0]
 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__default_rt_sa_restorer_v2+0) [0x766031a0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo22BSONElementManipulator9SetNumberEd+0x98) [0x3bfa40]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11ModSetState16applyModsInPlaceEb+0x3d4) [0x433a5c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14_updateObjectsEbPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES4_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEPNS_11RemoveSaverEbRKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyEb+0x2788) [0x430844]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13updateObjectsEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES4_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEbRKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyE+0x70) [0x431428]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14receivedUpdateERNS_7MessageERNS_5CurOpE+0x35c) [0x3c5dc8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0x14b0) [0x3c81a4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x9c) [0x182474]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x420) [0x64aa08]
```

Comment: how many documents are in this collection? If MongoDB cannot use an index to get documents in the requested sort order, the combined size of all documents in the sort operation, plus a small overhead, must be less than 32 megabytes.

Comment: @Astro about 3000 docs. P.S. in interactive shell sort works fine

Comment: It seems like your hardware is failing. Check your syslog for any suspicious entry.